# Exchange Calendar import

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, calendar, exchange

Being a freelance designer I have a shared iCloud calendar with my wife so she knows what to expect from my work week. I also have an exchange account cause of my Microsoft work but my wife can't see this. Is there any way to import my exchange calendar info to my iCloud calendar so my wife can be kept up to date?

Answer (score 1):

If this solution existed I would have been very pleased. Unfortunately I've been searching for this option a lot and the answer is **no**.

I'm currently using a work-around in which I've logged in with my Exchange account on the iPad at home and only checked the option to **display** the calendar of that particular Exchange account. (This also works for an iPhone or iPod Touch)

The calendar is now visible to everyone with access to the iDevice, and you can open and combine them in view. So you can see everything together even when it comes from multiple accounts.

I hope this is a possible solution which can work for you, as there is no easy way to **copy** or **sync** your calendar (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [iCloud Control Panel for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1455)?

> iCloud keeps mail, contacts, and calendars up to date between your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac, and Windows PC, and lets you share calendars and task lists.

Comment: This is not what the user is asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I definitely misread the question and assumed the iCloud account was shared. And sorry about the delay - totally missed this comment. Anyway, **this $20 product should do the trick**: http://www.codetwo.com/sync-for-icloud/?sts=2151